# jQuery mobile content area too high

Tags: jquery-mobile, height, fixed, sticky-footer

I have a problem with jquery mobile an its content-area.

Here i've made a little example:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/9EzFN/)

As you can see i am using the jquery mobile 1.1.0 rc1 in order to have a truely fixed footer. The footer works fine. The problem is the scrollbar on the right. Anyone got a recommendation how i can get rid of this problem ? What i've also noticed is, that the problem only appears if the footers data-position is set to "fixed".

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it'll fix your issue but you need a closing `</div>` tag after the `</ul>` tag so the DIV elements are properly nested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found a bug. Report it and consider using the stable version instead.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that the 1.1 rc1 almost supports the fixed toolbars, which i really need for my web-app. I'll give the the stable version another try. Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the bug reports on this and it seems that the issue is solved in the newest git build.

Comment: You could try and set the $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true; for version 1.0.1. It enables true fixed toolbars.